# How do I solve the $Ax=B$ equation where $A$ is not a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&2&0\\-3&0&2&1\\-4&-1&-2&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

I need to solve find $X$ in $AX=B$, where $B=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. How am I supposed to do this with $X=A^{-1}B$, as I cannot inverse A since it is not square?

Comment: 1 upvote for this but http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433994/definition-of-a-manifold not this? Grr this site! Also is it under or over constrained?

Comment: 4 unknowns and 3 equations...

Comment: Form the augmented matrix $[A\mid b]$, row-reduce, and go from there.

Comment: What does "solved" mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination
This is more fundamental than taking inverses of square matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&2&0\\-3&0&2&1\\-4&-1&-2&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the same as the following system of linear equations
$$\begin{matrix}
\ 2x_1&-x_2&+2x_3 &\ \ =&1\\
-3x_1&&+2x_3 &+x_4=&-1\\
-4x_1&-x_2&-2x_3 &-x_4=&0.
\end{matrix}$$

The number of equations is one less than the number of unknowns. So, we have to choose one of the unknowns to be the parameter of the solutions. Let $u=x_1$ and consider $u$ as a known quantity.

With this we have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{matrix}
-x_2 +&2x_3 &\ \ =&1-2u\\
&2x_3 &+x_4=&3u-1\\
-x_2-&2x_3 &-x_4=&4u
\end{matrix} \tag 1$$

which is equivalent to the following matrix equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 &2 &0\\
0&2&1\\
-1&-2&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1-2u\\
3u-1\\
4u
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can invert the $3\times 3$ matrix above if you like inverting matrices.

I would rather solve $(1)$ directly, though. For example we would immediately get

$$x_2=1-7u$$
by adding the second and the third equation of $(1)$.